# how to optimize "replaceFirst" method in java

Tags: java, replace, out-of-memory

i use httpclient to crawl htmls. In my code, i found

```
html = html.replaceFirst("[cC][hH][aA][rR][sS][eE][tT]\\s*?=\\s*?([gG][bB]2312|[gG][bB][kK]|[gG][bB]18030)","charset=utf-8");
```

above code cause java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.  The total program use 251MB, replaceFirst method use 64.8%, 157MB, and is growing. How can i avoid this, i need some help. ths~

Comment: You are attempting to replace "charset=gb2312" or "charset=gbk" or "charset=gb18030" with "charset-utf-8", case-insensitive, is that correct? Are you *sure* that is the cause of your memory issues? Can you make a minimal test program that demonstrates that that line of code is actually causing significant memory usage?

Comment: I just ran that replace 300k times on a 100k character string with and without a matching string and saw no unusual memory usage.

Comment: year, i'm sure. i have done several tests using jprofiler , at the point of the program clashing, "replaceFirst" method used nearly 90% of the total memory

Comment: How long is `html` when it crashes?

Answer (score 1):

First point is: do not use regular expressions for HTML parsing. Use HTML parser instead. 
Second, if you already have this pattern and just want to fix it a little bit try to understand what does it do.

It actually replaces `charset=GBK2312` or `charset=GBK18030` by `charset=UTF-8` using very not optimized way.

So, first change your regex to the following:

`charset=GBK(?:2312|18030)`

I believe this wiil already give you some advantage. But this regular expression is case sensitive. Instead of manually writing each character in lower and upper case use `Pattern` directly:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("charset=GBK(?:2312|18030)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
String newHtml = p.matcher(oldHtml).replaceFirst("charset=utf8");
```

Comment: The regex should be `charset=GB(?:K|2312|18030)`.